# coco API installation error in anaconda prompt

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I tried to install coco API in my anaconda environment by giving command:
pip install git+https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi.git#subdirectory=PythonAPI
But got an error:

Building wheel for (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [1 lines of output]
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
[end of output] but i have already installed this.
and another error:

× python setup.py clean did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for pycocotools
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pycocotools, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I was expecting to run the command. Please help to run this.